# obtaining npm --version via cmake execute_process

Tags: npm, cmake

I am trying to obtain npm version with cmake executable. For some reason when I run this code:

```
execute_process(COMMAND npm --version
               OUTPUT_VARIABLE NPM_VERSION)

message("npm: ${NPM_VERSION}")
```

I get the output:

```
npm: The system cannot find the file specified
```

whereas when I just run command in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019:

```
npm --version
```

I get correct output:

```
7.19.1
```

Does anyone the solution how to fix this?

EDIT: Addition of the result from cmd: `where npm` to the system enviroment path doesn't fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to make it work by passing absolute path to the npm obtained with `find_program(NPM_PATH npm)` and adding right extension for the system (eg. `execute_process(${NPM}.cmd --version OUTPUT_VARIABLE NPM_VERSION)` for Windows)